# Using hidden fields in formtastic

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I am using formtastic and if a user switches types a field switches from a select to a string input.

```
=f.input :name, :collection => Item::NAMES, :as => :select
=f.input :name
```

this works but I need to write those changes to a hidden field and pass that back.

```
=f.input :name, :as => :hidden
```

Right now I am trying to use jquery to detect change and write it to the hidden field.

```
$('#product_name').change(function(){
   ... write to field
});
```

how do I write to the hidden field? or simplify the labels being used in the field generation?

Answer (score 0):

To change the value of the hidden field

```
$('#name').val('somevalue');
```

Comment: ok the problem would also be that formtastic names all the fields the same thing.  is there a way to create a field with formtasitc without giving it a symbol representing a field.

Answer (score 0):

```
=f.input :name, :as => :hidden ,:id=> "name"

$('#product_name').change(function(){
  $('#name').val("xyzzz");
});
```

This field will automatically be posted with other params.

Comment: ok the problem would also be that formtastic names all the fields the same thing. is there a way to create a field with formtasitc without giving it a symbol representing a field?